# Fourier series coefficients gnuplot

Tags: c, gnuplot, fft

This program is supposed to find the coefficients of the fourier series, and then plot the function built from the calculated values.

the piecewise is

h(t)=1+(t/pi) for t<0
h(t)=1-(t/pi) for t>0

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "comphys.c"
#include "comphys.h"
#define pi 3.141592653589793

double trap1 (double l, double u, int m, int N);
double trap(double l,double u,int m,int N); // Use trapezoidal method
double inte(double x,int m);
double integrand(double x, int m); // This is the integrand of the bms
double w=1.0; //omega (here - w-2pi/Period where Period=2pi)
int main()
{
  FILE *out,*rsp;
  int m; // Index of the b coefficients
  int M=5; // Number of coeeficients to compute
  int T=201;  // Number of time steps 
  int t; // This is a counter to keep track of the h(t) function to plot
  double *b,*h,j,dj,*a,a0;
  double ll,ul;
  a=dvector(1,M);
  b=dvector(1,M);  // coefficients
  h=dvector(1,T);  // function built from Fourier terms
  ll=-pi;  // lower time limit
  ul=pi;   // upper time limit

  // Prepare to write for plotting
  printf("\nBrute force complex Fourier transform algorithm");
  if ((out=fopen("fs.out","w"))==NULL) {
    printf("\nCannot open file for output\n");
    getchar();
    return(0);          
  }

  // Loop through the wave numbers    
  for (m=1;m<=M;m++)
    {
      b[m]=(1.0/pi)*trap(ll,ul,m,T);
      a[m]=(1.0/pi)*trap1(ll,ul,m,T);
      printf("\nb[%d]=%f   a[%d]=%f",m,b[m],m,a[m]);

      // Build the h(t) function as we go
      t=0;
      dj=(ul-ll)/(double)T;
      for (j=ll;j<=ul;j+=dj)
    {
      t++;
      h[t]+=(b[m]*sin((double)m*w*j))+(a[m]*cos((double)m*w*j));
    }
    }

  // Write out for plotting
  t=0;
  for (j=ll;j<=ul;j+=dj)
    {
      t++;
      fprintf(out,"%f %f\n",j,h[t]);
    }
  fclose(out);
  printf("\nProgram complete without known error.\n");

  if((rsp = fopen("gnuplot.rsp","w")) == NULL)
    {
      printf("\nCannot open gnuplot.rsp for writing\n");
      exit(1);
    }
  fprintf(rsp,"plot '%s' using 1:2 with lines\n",out);
  fprintf(rsp,"pause mouse\n");
  fprintf(rsp,"replot\n");
  fclose(rsp);
  if(system("gnuplot gnuplot.rsp") == -1)
    {
      printf("\nCommand could not be executed\n");
      exit(1);
    }
  return;
}

double trap (double l, double u, int m, int N)

{
  double x,integral,dx;
  int i;

  if (u==l) return (0.0);
  dx=(u-l)/(double)(N-1);

  integral=0.0;
  integral+=0.5*(integrand(u,m)-integrand(l,m));
  x=l+dx;
  for (i=1;i<N;i++)
    {
      integral += integrand(x,m);
      x+=dx;
    }
  integral*=dx;
  printf("\n%f\n",integral);
  return(integral);
}

double trap1 (double l, double u, int m, int N)
{
  double x,integral,dx;
  int i;

  if (u==l) return (0.0);
  dx=(u-l)/(double)(N-1);

  integral=0.0;
  integral+=0.5*(inte(u,m)-inte(l,m));
  x=l+dx;
  for (i=1;i<N;i++)
    {
      integral += inte(x,m);
      x+=dx;
    }
  integral*=dx;
  return(integral);
}


double integrand(double x, int m)
{
  if (x<0) return (sin((double)m*w*x)+((x/pi)*sin((double)m*w*x)));
  return(sin((double)m*w*x)-((x/pi)*sin((double)m*w*x)));
}

double inte(double x,int m)
{
  if (x<0) return (cos((double)m*w*x)+((x/pi)*cos((double)m*w*x)));
  return(cos((double)m*w*x)-((x/pi)*cos((double)m*w*x)));
}
```

The problem I am have is, it compiles fine and list out the coefficients(No idea if they are right or anything), but at the end when trying to plot it gives me

"cant read data file "?,??"
"gnuplot.rsp", line:1 util.c: No such file or directory"

And I dont know how to fix that. Ive plotted plenty of programs with gnuplot, so it shouldnt be a missing file or anything.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that you're running the program in the same directory where `gnuplot.rsp` is in? It seems that you simply don't have current working directory which contains the file named so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here:

```
fprintf(rsp,"plot '%s' using 1:2 with lines\n",out);
```

you should use directly the string "fs.out" and not "out" which is a FILE pointer (and also already closed).